# How to add CSS class to Drupal 7 views exposed form

Tags: drupal-7

I would like a Drupal 7 theme function to add some bootstrap CSS to a view form.

Specifically I want to add the .form-inline CSS class to the HTML form element.

Answer (score 0):

```
function themename_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {  

  if ($form_id=='views_exposed_form') { 
    $view = $form_state['view'];
    if ($view->name == 'sc_search' && $view->current_display == 'panel_pane_1' ) {
        $form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'form-inline';        
    }
  }
}
```